# How to setup Yahoo messenger in Empathy?

Tags: 11.10, empathy, yahoo

After upgrading to 11.10, Empathy is not connecting to Yahoo Messenger. What are the new setup steps?

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for Yahoo, because I don't have an account and don't wish to set one up, but on opening empathy it brings you a setup window.  Go to the dash and type in empathy. Just tried it with gmail and facebook, both work.  If you skipped this, you can try again from Edit>Accounts.  If you already made one and would like to add your yahoo, go to Edit>Accounts and click on the "plus" at the bottom left, and select "yahoo" in the dropdown, then fill out your info.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Easy without too much trouble.

1. Open Empathy. either in the Dash or in the icon above for the Chat.
2. If no accounts are created the account creation will appear. If there is an already existing account for any of the other chat services just press <kbd>F4</kbd> to make the Account Window appear.
3. Click on the **ADD** Button.
4. In the **Protocol** List (The first option before inserting your user and password select **Yahoo!** (If you use the Japan version select **Yahoo! Japan**)
5. Insert ONLY the username and you password. The part about **@yahoo.com** is not needed.

   An example is shown here:

   [image]
6. Click APPLY button and done.

NOTE: The above switch that says **On** is if you want the account to be activated or not. Just in case you have several accounts.